# Get the position of the GanttPresenterSplitter in a <telerik:RadGanttView>

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, telerik

I am working on a WPF application using Telerik and coded in C# .NET.
My following question goes over a XAML page using the model “Code behind” to implement the logic of the page.

I would like to get the position of the GanttPresenterSplitter in a telerik:RadGanttView.
This information would allow me to set the position of another element in another part of the same screen.
I would also know if it is possible to add an event handler on that GanttPresenterSplitter in order to get its position each time that line moves.

The ASP .NET page is split into 3 parts (please find in attachment [draft_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXySX.png)) :

- Red square : telerik:RadGanttView
- Green square : telerik:RadGridView
- Blue square : telerik:RadScheduleView

As you can see, there is a dividing line between telerik:RadGridView and telerik:RadScheduleView.
I would like that line moves at the same time and same position as the GanttPresenterSplitter in the RadGanttView.

Using a more explicit picture based on an example (please find in attachment [explicit_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBiq2.png)) :

- Orange line : GanttPresenterSpliter
- Purple line : GridSplitter

My point is to coordinate the orange and the purple lines in order they have the same position all the time.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to get the position of the GanttPresenterSplitter, however, you could, for example, get the Width of the Grid area of the GanttView, and more specifically the width of the visible area. It is presented by a ScrollBar element, so you could subscribe to its SizeChanged event to handle when the Grid area is resized.
I have prepared a sample example to demonstrate the approach, please download the attachment and give it a try.